# create an Output in Cloudformation Stack with Fn::Select

Tags: aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to create an Output of a stack like that at all:

```
TargetGroupARN1Part:
 Description: the final portion of the target group ARN
 Value:
  Fn::Select:
  - 5
  - Fn::Split:
    - ":"
    - !Ref WebTG
```

When I try it I get:

```
Template format error: Invalid outputs property : [Fn::Select]
```

merci A

Comment: This snippet worked fine on my test. Can you review the rest of your template?

Comment: FYI you can also use the short form, as `Value: !Select [5, !Split [':', !Ref WebTG]]`

Comment: That worked, thank you @tyron

Comment: glad to hear! i moved the comments into an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be working, as it worked on my tests.

You could also try the short form, such as:

```
TargetGroupARN1Part:
   Description: the final portion of the target group ARN
   Value: !Select [5, !Split [':', !Ref WebTG]]
```